# how to return multilevel categories in multidimensional array with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am trying to get multidimensional array from categories saved in database with recursion but i am unable to properly format the output i need.

i have tried following code which is working fine if i want to output ul-li multi-level list but not working when i am trying to convert it into array

```
function get_categories($parent_id=0){
    global $link;

    $menu=[];

    $sql="SELECT * from terms where parent='$parent_id'";

    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);


    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $sub_cats=get_categories($row['id']);

      $menu[$row['name']]=$sub_cats;
    }

    return $menu;
  }
```

and db schema is in attached file
[db schema looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv0at.png)

expected output is

```
array(
  [0]=>array(
    ['name']=>language
    ['sub_cats']=>array(
      [0]=>array(
        [name]=>english
        ['sub_cats']=>array(
          [0]=>array(
            [name]=>john milton
            ['sub_cats']=>0
          )
          [1]=>array(
            [name]=>william blake
            ['sub_cats']=>0
          )
        )
      )
      [1]=>array(
        ['name']=>spanish
        ['sub_cats']=>0
      )
      [2]=>array(
        ['name']=>sanskrit
        ['sub_cats']=>0
      )
    )
  )
  [1]=>array(
    ['name']=>xyz
    ['sub_cats']=>0
  )
)
```

**current output is**

```
Array
(
    [Language] => Array
        (
            [english] => Array
                (
                    [abcd] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [hindi] => Array
                (
                )

            [sanskrit] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [science] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

or any other format which can be easily transported via JSON and interpreted via JavaScript on other side.

and i know i am using multiple queries which can slow down the process, so if possible tell me the correct way.

also i am using mysqli for now to grasp the concept and i will shift my code in prepared statements later.

Comment: First, I think it better to get all the category from the DB first and manipulate them with the recursive function after they are in PHP array. Second, what is your current output?

Comment: can you post database schema with sample entries?

Comment: i have edited the question for current output

Comment: i have edited the question for db schema as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$menu = [];


function get_categories($parent_id = 0, &$menu)
{
    global $mysqli;

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from terms where parent=?")) {

        $stmt->bind_param("i", $parent_id);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $reference = &$menu[];
            $reference['name'] = $row['name'];
            $sub_cats = get_categories($row['id'], $reference);
            $reference['sub_cats'] = $sub_cats ? $sub_cats : 0;

        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}

get_categories(0,$menu);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($menu);
echo '<pre>';
```

I have used mysqli prepared statements, just to avoid sql injection and I recommend you to use prepared statements as well.

Output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => language
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => english
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => john milton
                            [sub_cats] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => william blake
                            [sub_cats] => 0
                        )

                    [sub_cats] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => spanish
                    [sub_cats] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => sanskrit
                    [sub_cats] => 0
                )

            [sub_cats] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => xyz
            [sub_cats] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: i actually wrote it there that i am using mysqli until i grasp the concept anyway thanks alot for the code

`$reference['sub_cats'] = get_categories($row['id'], $reference) ? get_categories($row['id'], $reference) : 0;`

can u explain this line please ?

Comment: and there is a small problem here, `sub_cats` are always zero, i need to replace it with an array if there are sub categories of current `categories`, if u can explain the above line, i think i can sort out the problem from here.

Comment: @harshitmishra try my updated code and check whether it works for you.

Comment: `$reference['sub_cats'] = $sub_cats ? $sub_cats : 0;` please explain me what this line is doing, if it is a simple if-else logic please convert it into if else
and then i can edit it the way i want.

Comment: @harshitmishra that line tells php if `$sub_cats` is not null `$reference['sub_cats']` will have `$sub_cats`  otherwise `0`

Comment: i think ur code is helping me understand how this thing works, thanks for the quick help :)